# Does any OpenCL host have more than one platform?

Tags: opencl

The definition of a platform in Khronos' OpenCL 1.0 and 1.1 [specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/):

> Platform: The host plus a collection of devices managed by the OpenCL framework that allow an application to share resources and execute kernels on devices in the platform.

The OpenCL function [clGetPlatformIDs](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html) creates an array of platforms, implying that multiple platforms are possible.  Is it safe to assume that a given OpenCL host has only one platform?

In other words, will I lose anything on any host by doing this:

```
cl_platform_id platform_id;
cl_uint num_platforms;
errcode = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &num_platforms);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on there being only one Platform. When you have multiple OpenCL implementations on one system (which should be possible with the OpenCL ICD, although I'm not sure if that is only planned or already finished), you should get multiple platforms, one for each opencl implementation. One example where there could be multiple opencl implementations would be an nvidia implementation to run opencl on gpu and an amd implementation to run on cpu, so that it not that far fetched either.

edit: look at http://developer.amd.com/support/KnowledgeBase/Lists/KnowledgeBase/DispForm.aspx?ID=71 for (better) desciption of this

Comment: Multiple platforms on the same host are a fact.

Answer (score 8):

To complement the answer of Tim Child with an example (Thinkpad X201 with both AMD and Intel SDK's installed):

```
$ python /usr/share/doc/python-pyopencl/examples/benchmark-all.py
Execution time of test without OpenCL:  10.9563219547 s
===============================================================
Platform name: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Platform profile: FULL_PROFILE
Platform vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Platform version: OpenCL 1.1 AMD-APP-SDK-v2.5 (684.213)
---------------------------------------------------------------
Device name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz
Device type: CPU
Device memory:  7799 MB
Device max clock speed: 2399 MHz
Device compute units: 2
Execution time of test: 0.00842799 s
Results OK
===============================================================
Platform name: Intel(R) OpenCL
Platform profile: FULL_PROFILE
Platform vendor: Intel(R) Corporation
Platform version: OpenCL 1.1 LINUX
---------------------------------------------------------------
Device name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz
Device type: CPU
Device memory:  7799 MB
Device max clock speed: 2400 MHz
Device compute units: 2
Execution time of test: 0.00260659 s
Results OK
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is one Platform Id  for each vendors OpenCL installation.  So if you install AMD's and Intel's OpenCL SDK's you will get one Platform Id for each.

Comment: So if someone has an AMD APU + an AMD GPU does it give one platform or two ? What about an AMD APU + an Nvidia GPU ?

Comment: For  an  AMD APU + an AMD GPU  1  platform, and for AMD APU + a Nvidia GPU, 2 platforms. Why?  all AMD only require 1 SDK, AMD + Nivida require 2 SDK's.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you assume that a host has only one platform, you would have to figure out what the Id of that platform is, before calling [clGetPlatformInfo](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformInfo.html). So its better if you call  clGetPlatformIDs, pick up a default or user supplied platform and then call clGetPlatformInfo.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying and I agree; you can't do much without a platform id.  I think my question was unclear when you read it, so I've added an example.

Comment: The documentation says that you can pass a NULL argument when getting the device ID to create a context but it doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: Yeah passing NULL is implementation-defined behaviour. It will as an example cause your code to fail on AMD's OpenCL implementation, but  work fine on nVidia's.