# What is a host in opencl?

Tags: opencl, host

I have started now to learn openCL. I am doing the tutorial now but I can't really grasp the idea is of host could someone explain.Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenCL is a system designed to support massively parallel processing such as can be performed by modern graphics chips (GPUs).  In the OpenCL paradigm, a "host program" is the outer control logic that performs the configuration for a GPU-based application.  This host program normally would run on a general purpose CPU (such as the x86-compatible main processor in most desktop PCs).  An OpenCL program also contains one or more "kernel" functions that are designed for parallel execution on the GPU.

Once all of the buffers and kernels are configured, the host program will call something like

```
EnqueueNDRangeKernel()
```

which will begin execution of the kernel on the GPU.

Depending on your target platform, things could be a little different.  For example, OpenCL does not specifically require the existence of a GPU.  In can instead execute the kernel as multiple threads on the same CPU that runs the host program.

Summary of OpenCL nomenclature:

- *Host* - the main CPU used to configure kernel execution
- *Device* - the component which contains the processing units that will execute the kernel (the GPU)

Comment: so,how when performing clGetPlatformIDs it is possible to get several platforms?
(Seems that we are working from the single host)

Comment: With clGetPlatformIDs you can a list of all available platforms and with clGetDeviceIDs you can get a list of all available device for a platform.

Comment: It might be said that the OpenCL API is over-generalized.  I don't know why clGetPlatformIDs() would return more than 1 platform -- maybe that would be another good question for SO.  There is a lot of boilerplate code involved in getting an OpenCL program to work.  The best way to get started with OpenCL is probably to find a working example rather than trying to build one from scratch.

Comment: Platform: The host plus a collection of devices managed by the OpenCL framework that allow an application to share resources and execute kernels on devices in the platform.  The OpenCL Specification: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf

Comment: You can easily have more than 1 plarform - e g Intel CPU with integrated graphics plus discrete GPU

Comment: My **guess** about *multiple platforms*: The *platform* has more to do with who provides the OpenCL software than what *devices* are installed on your system (although the software might be tied to the device).  Still, this doesn't really answer the question of how you could make use of multiple *platforms* from a single vendor's library implementation.  Answers to this question: [Does any OpenCL host have more than one platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444664/does-any-opencl-host-have-more-than-one-platform) provide evidence that **using** multiple platforms is possible.