# OpenCL only one device in a platform

Tags: opencl, host, gpu

I am learning OpenCL from the beginning and get confused by **platform = host + device** idea. In my work PC there are 2 platforms detected: Platform 0 has only the CPU, Platform 1 has only the NVIDIA GPU. [Detected platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYgfb.png)

This PC actually has also an Intel GPU but I assume that it doesn't support OpenCL so it does not show here. My question goes: In an OpenCL application there are host and device. Normally the host and device come from one platform according to my understanding from book . Then in my PC I need to use either the CPU or the NVIDIA GPU as both host and device for the OpenCL application. Is this true?

I tried to search by myself, some answers indeed help me to understand more in this topic like this one: [What is a host in opencl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485253/what-is-a-host-in-opencl). But about using one hardware for both host and device is not being answered or confirmed by my searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're mixing up some terminology here.

- The **host** is the regular program executing on the CPU itself.
- The **platforms** are provided by OpenCL drivers, representing a set of devices and features.
- The **devices** are underlying hardware that may be used for OpenCL, provided by a platform.

A platform may provide multiple different devices: For example, if you have the Nvidia OpenCL driver installed, it provides an OpenCL device for every supported GPU. Meanwhile, the Intel driver provides the Intel CPU as an OpenCL device.

Generally, your program flow will look something like this:

1. Find OpenCL platforms using `clGetPlatformIds`
2. Find OpenCL devices using `clGetDeviceIds` for whichever platform(s) you want to use.
3. Create the OpenCL context, program, command queue, and kernel using `clCreateContext`, `clCreateProgram`, etc.
4. Copy necessary data to buffers or kernel parameters.
5. Execute the kernel on one or more devices using `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel`.
6. Copy data back from buffers

Comment: Thank you @apemanzilla for your explanation. So the host is not a "hardware"  but the "master program" which will be executing on the CPU. Then in one platform the CPU is also provided as a device. In this situation, I can use the CPU both executing my host program and as my OpenCL device executing kernals following the workflow you described. Is my understanding correct?